Background overlapping drawer menu on react native
I'm new to React Native, and trying to create a background component to wrap my whole app so I don't need to care about it throught the pages. But when I try to wrap it around my drawer component, it overlaps it. How would I correctly manage this background?
The current background component:
import React from "react";
import { ViewStyle, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

const Background = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <LinearGradient
            colors={["#B2E2E2", "#008080"]}
            locations={[0, 1]}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0.3 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0.7 }}
            style={style.background}>
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" />
                <View style={{height: 50}}/>
                {children}
            </SafeAreaView>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
};
const style = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex: 1,
    }
});

export default Background;

the actual drawer component:
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import {Drawer} from "expo-router/drawer";
export default function DrawerLayout() {
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Drawer>
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="index"
                    options={{ 
                        title: "Inicio",
                        drawerLabel: "Inicio",
                        }} />
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="packing_list" 
                    options={{ 
                        title: "Packing List",
                        drawerLabel: "Packing List",
                        }} />
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="login" 
                    options={{ 
                        title: "Login",
                        drawerLabel: "Login",
                        }} />
            </Drawer>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    )
};

And the layout page:
import Background from "@/components/Background";
import DrawerLayout from "@/layouts/Drawer";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <Background>
        <DrawerLayout />
    </Background>
  );
}

triend z-index of background to -1 but guess that is not the issue
